# Google sheets first row based on other rows data?

Tags: google-sheets

I have got a data in the format below:

[image]

How can I have output as below using arrya_formula in the status column? Thanks in advance!

[image]

*Thanks*

Comment: What is the logic of the status? Does it print out whichever column has a 'fail'?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for but using array_formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that 'A B C' is one of your rows, because I don't think there is a way to pass column IDs through sheet formulas, you can use `=concatenate(arrayformula(if(A2:C2="fail",$A$1:$C$1,"")))`.  This won't give you the comma delimited version you asked for, but it does provide the same functionality.

Comment: This works, but how can I make this formula work pasting in only one cell?

Comment: I'm using this formula` ArrayFormula(IF((A2:A):(C2:C)="fail",$A$1:$C$1,))` It works fine but outputs get spread across columns, is there any way to have the outputs within a single cell for each row?

Comment: The `ArrayFormula` mode is to look at an array, and output an array based on the formula.  So if you have 3 columns, it will spit out 3 columns.  That is why Tirtha and I used `concatenate`.  `Concatenate` combines the array data into a single cell.  You can't paste the formula into a single cell and have it work for the whole array.  It has to work row by row (in your case), so you need to copy down your 'status' column for the number of rows you have data.

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not get rid of the comma at the end, this is close to what you want. To get rid of the last comma, I guess, you need to write a script.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(IF(A1:C1="fail", CHOOSE(COLUMN(A1:C1), "A, ", "B, ", "C, "), "")))
```

**Result:** For the second table you posted...

B,

A, B,

A, B, C,

---

*Edit:*

Removing the trailing commas are supposed to be easy. Don't know why I didn't think about it before. The following gives exactly what you want.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(IF(A1:C1="fail", CHOOSE(COLUMN(A1:C1), "A, ", "B, ", "C, "), ""))), ", $", "")
```

**Result:** For the second table you posted...

B

A, B

A, B, C